# Calculating the power of a cluster vs a single workstation

Tags: cluster, distributed-computing

For the same price we can get either

Worktsation which is 2 x 6 core Xeons 3.4GHz, 128GB RAM, 600GB SAS RAID 0

= 12 Cores, 128GB RAM

Or

Cluster 8 x (4 Core i7 3.4GHz, 16GB RAM, 250GB SATA, Intel 82579LM), Gigabit ethernet Netgear switch

= 32 Cores, 128GB RAM

Which is better? More FLOPS etc.?  With the cluster having 3 times as many cores, does that make up for the gigabit ethernet interconnect? (vs the workstation with all ram on the same bus).

It's for running custom C programs doing bio-informatics.

EDIT this is a real question as the person who wants it came in asking about the two, a workstation vs a "Linux cluster" ~ £5000.  From web searching I found i7 is ~80GFLOPS and Xeon is ~90GFLOPs... Workstation =~ 180GFLOPS  vs  8 PCs=~ 640GFLOPS  That 640GFLOPs would come down after taking into account parallelising overheads and ethernet bottleneck.

Comment: Virtually impossible to answer your question as you've provided zero information regarding the most important part - what clustering software are you looking to use and how does that work. In terms of raw cycles the 4xi7 solution is obviously more capacious but it's useless without the right clustering system, even then ethernet may have too much latency.

Comment: They are looking to run a Linux cluster? Yes from the raw numbers it seems 32 cores win. But my concern is the limits from gigabit ethernet.    File sizes are 2- 4GBs.

Comment: No such thing as a 'linux cluster' - there's clusters than run on linux but the servers don't just all suddenly work together magically on their own - you need some "clustering software" - hence my question.

Comment: I'd imagine they would want something free and open source. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, you're really not getting this. How about if I asked you for a recommendation for just "some form of transportation system" - could be a bike, could be an aircraft carrier or anything in between - i.e. you're telling us NOTHING here - "a cluster", to do WHAT???

Comment: Hax - you need to know what this 'cluster' is going to be actually doing, what are they wanting to use computers to actually achieve and what software do they intend to use to achieve this - CPUs alone do nothing functional, you still haven't come to use with this information.

Comment: I've been trying to find out, but from what I remember the dataset is large (genome data) and the calculations are simple, as in comparisons/ finding differences.

Comment: Hax, this means NOTHING, nothing at all - are you trying to troll us, 'cos you keep coming back with zero useful information - tell whoever's asking you to go away because neither you nor them know enough to be considering this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cluster gives you a little more power and some redundancy(if it's feasible for your software). The big 'workstation' has the advantage of being simpler to deploy and won't be bottlenecked by your switch. I can't say for certain if the switch will bottleneck since it will depend on your transfer sizes, etc.

Comment: I found this graph which helped from Amdahls law:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AmdahlsLaw.svg

Comment: How? How did that help in any way?

Answer (score 2):

This ***totally*** depends on the workload you need to run on the system and how well it can scale in a clustered environment.

Comment: Agreed. For example rendering (small data, tons of calculation) is a lot different than... some sort of financial simulation (super fast file streaming for every run). It also depends on CPU usag "per core".

Comment: Large data set, simple calculation (comparisons)?

Comment: You may as well tell us what you had for breakfast, it makes as much sense - how many times do we have to ask - tell us some real information, not just tiny peripheral rubbish.